# Last 2 Months and weeks in one column - Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 calendars in Dax:
CALENDAR (Date, MMM-YY, Week (start from Saturday till Friday)
CALENDAR PREVIOUS (copy of calendar 1 to show the last 4 weeks and last 2 months)
I have a date filter picked from CALENDAR.

I want a measure to show MTD values for last two months from selected date and count for the the IDs from start of the month of selected date.

Eg. Selected date= 19th Jan 2024

Return

| Timeline | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Nov'23 | 234 |
| Dec'23 | 789 |
| 1-5 Jan'24 | 87 |
| 6-12 Jan'24 | 65 |
| 13-19 Jan'24 | 45 |

Comment: You cannot create a dynamic table during report runtime. Suggest you consider having a Matrix with Month and Week in the `Rows`.